# Jquery Mobile - $.mobile.changepage not doing transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

So I am transitioning to a page doing this:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "newPage.html",  "fade");
```

but for some reason the page is not showing the fancy transition the way it should.  Does anyone know why this may be happening?  JQM is loading all right and everything seems to be functioning properly except the page transitions.  Do you need to do anything special to configure the page transitions?

This is JQM-B2 btw.

Comment: Firefox 5.  Do you think that is the issue?  I am just testing it on the desktop for the time being

Comment: Try Chrome, FF isn't great with transitions

Comment: The problem is, I am using mockjax to mock up API calls, and of course, that is not working in Chrome.  I do notice that the demo transitions on the JQM site works fine.  I am thinking that there is something wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Firefox won't do transitions for you. Try it on mobile. And I have no idea how you made transitions from demo run in FF. They donb't work for me in FF6

Comment: You're right.  It worked fine in the simulator, but not luck in FF5.  If you want to write a quick answer, I will give you credit for that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transitions used by Jquery Mobile rely on CSS 3 transition effects that FF is not able to replicate correctly. I would suggest using Desktop Safari as your desktop testing browser as it will do a better job of replicating how Mobile Safari will act.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.mobile.changePage( "../login/login.html", { transition: "none"});
```